# Pandas: Find duplicates in one column where there are exact two different values in second column

Tags: pandas, duplicates

Let us define the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "i"], 
                   ["A", "i"], 
                   ["A", "a"], 
                   ["B", "i"], 
                   ["B", "i"],
                   ["C", "a"],
                   ["C", "a"],
                   ["D", "a"],
                   ["D", "i"]], columns=['device', 'status'])
```

What I want to find now is a device, where there is at least one status of **a** and one of **i**. Then I would like to change all **i** to **a** and remove duplicates.

I imagine the first step to show the rows in question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "i"], 
                   ["A", "i"], 
                   ["A", "a"], 
                   ["D", "a"],
                   ["D", "i"]], columns=['device', 'status'])
```

The second step should then replace the **i** with **a**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "a"], 
                   ["A", "a"], 
                   ["A", "a"], 
                   ["D", "a"],
                   ["D", "a"]], columns=['device', 'status'])
```

The the duplicates should be removed, so I would end up with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "a"], 
                   ["D", "a"]], columns=['device', 'status'])
```

The background is that I have several devices that currently show different status. Only if all occurences are on i (inactive), I can show the overall status as inactive for this device. Otherwise it would have to be treated as if any occurrence was still active.

While I could handle step 2) and 3), I just cannot find a way for step 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is get `device` values with `a` and `i` values by comparing by `set`s and then new DataFrame by constructor:

```
s = df.groupby('device')['status'].apply(set)
idx = s.index[s == set(['a','i'])]
print (idx)
Index(['A', 'D'], dtype='object', name='device')

df = pd.DataFrame({'device': idx, 'status':'a'})
print (df)
  device status
0      A      a
1      D      a
```

If want all your steps:

```
df = df[df['device'].isin(idx)].replace({'status':{'i':'a'}}).drop_duplicates()
print (df)
  device status
0      A      a
7      D      a
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for this very quick answer.

Comment: There is one follow up question I have. Is there a way to alter idx = s.index[s == set(['a','i'])] in a way, that also these items are added that are "a" only, so idx would contain elements with "a" and "("a" and "i")?

Comment: Then use `s.index[(s == set(['a','i'])) | (s == set(['a'])) ]`

Comment: And it means  `a, i` or only `a`

Comment: One follow up question. Imagine, we had many more possible status (not only "a" and "i") and I wanted to find the ones, that have at least one "a" (so "a" plus any variances like "a, b" or "a, c, g". How could I create a kind of placeholder like (s == set(['a','*']))?